# How to setImageDrawable to scaled ImageButton without losing quality?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have an ImageButton and scaling it with animation:

```
imageButton.animate().scaleY(newSize / currentHeight)
```

After that, I'm trying to set an image using `setImageDrawable` and I'm getting an unexpected result: the image is pixelated.

I've figured the reason: when scaling ImageButton it's width & height are not changed. And when setting drawable ImageButton uses "unscaled" width and height.

So how to avoid this pixelization when setting drawable to the scaled ImageButton?

Comment: Use `ObjectAnimator` for animations and use vectors drawables.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun I use vector drawable, but this doesn't help.

Comment: Try `ObjectAnimator`